# ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT when calling google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues in Golang

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to run a simple go program calling the Google Sheets API:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    srv, err := sheets.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get("1HG_cmqALkquc0ud8Pm7GKOhR5IpPSj20q_fFkHBaM5M", "A1").Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%+v", resp.Values))
}
```

But when I try to run it, I get:

```
$ rm /home/johan/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
$ gcloud auth application-default login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=764086051850-6qr4p6gpi6hn506pt8ejuq83di341hur.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fsqlservice.login+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=W...s&access_type=offline&code_challenge=q...4&code_challenge_method=S256


Credentials saved to file: [/home/johan/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]

These credentials will be used by any library that requests Application Default Credentials (ADC).

Quota project "questions-279902" was added to ADC which can be used by Google client libraries for billing and quota. Note that some services may still bill the project owning the resource.

$ go run sheets_api.go 
panic: googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "method": "google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues",
      "service": "sheets.googleapis.com"
    },
    "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
  }
]

More details:
Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission


goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/johan/20q/cmd/labelserver/sheets_api.go:20 +0x194
exit status 2
```

I created this Google Sheet, so my user should have access to it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: because that token don't have permission to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can scope your token like that in Go

```
...
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cred, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly")
    srv, err := sheets.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentials(cred))
...
```

However, you could (should?) have subsequent errors. I [wrote that article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/access-to-google-workspace-documents-from-cloud-build-3001c2883b66) that mention that Sheet access issue with Cloud Build (based on Python, because most of the dev use Python, but I'm a go developer, I will be able to help you in Go if you need).

The article present different way to scope a token, one of them will work for you, according to the underlying environment.